# beamer, tabular* and array - illegal pream-token

Tags: tables, beamer, arrays, preamble

I am trying to fit a tabular* to a beamer page. However, it produces a significant amount of errors. I searched stackexchange and google but were not able to understand nor solve the problem by myself.

Could you help me to understand and fix the error messages?

Note 1: The frame looks good as it is, I just need to understand the error messages.
Note 2: The preamble contains commands and packages that I need for the other frames in my presentation.

Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\usetheme{default}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, textcomp}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx, threeparttable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzstyle{block}=[draw opacity=0.7,line width=1.4cm]

\newcommand{\beginbackup}{
\newcounter{framenumbervorappendix}
\setcounter{framenumbervorappendix}{\value{framenumber}}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
\usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\hspace*{2em}
\insertframenumber{} \hspace*{2ex}%
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
\vskip0pt%
}
}
\newcommand{\backupend}{
\addtocounter{framenumbervorappendix}{-\value{framenumber}}
\addtocounter{framenumber}{\value{framenumbervorappendix}} 
}
\robustify{\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}

\centering

\fontsize{4}{5}\selectfont

\renewcommand\theadfont{\fontsize{4}{5}\selectfont}
\settowidth{\rotheadsize}{\fontsize{4}{5}\selectfont Total}
\renewcommand{\theadalign}{bc}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % default: 6pt

\begin{tabular*}{\hsize}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                    *{31}{Z{4.5ex}}
              >{}S[table-format=2.0,
                            detect-weight]
                         }
    \toprule

\thead{(1)}   & \thead{(2)}  & \thead{(3)}  & \thead{(4)}   & \thead{(5)}   &
\thead{(6)}   & \thead{(7)}  & \thead{(8)}  & \thead{(9)}   & \thead{(10)}  &
\thead{(11)}  & \thead{(12)} & \thead{(13)} & \thead{(14)}  & \thead{(15)}  &
\thead{(16)}  & \thead{(17)} & \thead{(18)} & \thead{(19)}  & \thead{(20)}  &
\thead{(21)}  & \thead{(22)} & \thead{(23)} & \thead{(24)}  & \thead{(25)}  &
\thead{(26)}  & \thead{(27)} & \thead{(28)} & \thead{(29)}  & \thead{(30)}  &
\thead{(31)}  & \thead{(32)} & {\thead{(33)}}\\

        \cmidrule{1-33} 

\thead[lb]{XXX}
    & \rothead{1985}    & \rothead{1986}    & \rothead{1987}    & \rothead{1988}
    & \rothead{1989}    & \rothead{1990}    & \rothead{1991}    & \rothead{1992}
    & \rothead{1993}    & \rothead{1994}    & \rothead{1995}    & \rothead{1996}
    & \rothead{1997}    & \rothead{1998}    & \rothead{1999}    & \rothead{2000}
    & \rothead{2001}    & \rothead{2002}    & \rothead{2003}    & \rothead{2004}
    & \rothead{2005}    & \rothead{2006}    & \rothead{2007}    & \rothead{2008}
    & \rothead{2009}    & \rothead{2010}    & \rothead{2011}    & \rothead{2012}
    & \rothead{2013}    & \rothead{2014}    & \rothead{2015}    & {\rothead{Total}}\\

\midrule
    XXX &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{I} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{F} &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{2} \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} XXX &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{I} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{F} &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{2} \\
    XXX &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{I} &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{1} \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} XXX &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{I} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{1} \\
    XXX & \multicolumn{1}{c}{I} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{F} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{2} \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} XXX &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{I} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{F} &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{2} \\
    XXX &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{I} &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{F} &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{2} \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} XXX &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{I} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{F} &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{2} \\
    XXX &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{I} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{I} &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{F} &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{3} \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} XXX &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{0} \\
    XXX &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{0} \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} XXX &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{II} &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{2} \\
    XXX &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{F} &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{1} \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} XXX &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{I} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{1} \\
    XXX &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{I} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{F} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{F} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{3} \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{XXX} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{24} \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886}  \\
    XXX &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{I} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{1} \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} XXX &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{I} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{1} \\
    XXX &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{0} \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} XXX &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{0} \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{XXX} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{2} \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886}  \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .949,  .949,  .949} XXX &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{0} \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886}  \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .886,  .886,  .886} \textbf{XXX} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{26} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}% 

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

File list without siunitx (with siunitx there is no output created):

```
 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2017/01/23 v3.41 A class for typesetting presentations
etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
beamerbasemodes.sty    
beamerbasedecode.sty    
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
beamerbaseoptions.sty    
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2016/05/09 v1.0r Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.10 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
colortbl.sty    2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)
   array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 At begin shipout hook (HO)
hyperref.sty    2016/05/21 v6.83p Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2016/05/21 v6.83p Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2016/05/21 v6.83p Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    
beamerbasefont.sty    
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2013/03/28
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
beamerbasetranslator.sty    
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
beamerbasemisc.sty    
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    
beamerbasetitle.sty    
beamerbasesection.sty    
beamerbaseframe.sty    
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    
beamerbaseframesize.sty    
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    
beamerbasecolor.sty    
beamerbasenotes.sty    
beamerbasetoc.sty    
beamerbasetemplates.sty    
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    
beamerbaseboxes.sty    
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    
enumerate.sty    2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    
beamerbasetheorems.sty    
 amsmath.sty    2016/03/10 v2.15b AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2015/03/04 v2.20.2
beamerbasethemes.sty    
beamerthemedefault.sty    
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    
   babel.sty    2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of babel
 english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
   times.sty    2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (SPQR) 
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
  ts1enc.dfu    2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
longtable.sty    2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
  lscape.sty    2000/10/22 v3.01 Landscape Pages (DPC)
rotating.sty    2009/03/28 v2.16a rotated objects in LaTeX
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
multirow.sty    
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
makecell.sty    2009/08/03 V0.1e Managing of Tab Column Heads and Cells
tabularx.sty    2016/02/03 v2.11 `tabularx' package (DPC)
threeparttable.sty    2003/06/13  v 3.0
adjustbox.sty    2012/05/21 v1.0 Adjusting TeX boxes (trim, clip, ...)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
 adjcalc.sty    2012/05/16 v1.1 Provides advanced setlength with multiple back-ends (calc, etex, pgfmath)
trimclip.sty    2012/05/16 v1.0 Trim and clip general TeX material
collectbox.sty    2012/05/17 v0.4b Collect macro arguments as boxes
tc-pdftex.def    2012/05/13 v1.0 Clipping driver for pdftex
ifoddpage.sty    2016/04/23 v1.1 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
  natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
 mathabx.sty    2003/07/29 v0.0 Non-standard LaTeX package mathabx
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
ragged2e.sty    2009/05/21 v2.1 ragged2e Package (MS)
everysel.sty    2011/10/28 v1.2 EverySelectfont Package (MS)
  ts1cmr.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
  t1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
Rigorosum.out
Rigorosum.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict    
 ot1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  omllmm.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omslmsy.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omxlmex.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
 ***********
```

Comment: You haven't loaded `siunitx`, required for the `S` column specifier

Comment: you are using S columns but have not included the `siunitx` package that defines them

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need `graphicx` with beamer and maybe you could fined the `appendixnumberbeamer` package useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that almost always with TeX you should only look at the *first* error, later errors (if you scroll past the first) are likely to be spurious generated from attempted recovery actions.

the error here is quite clear

```
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (S): `c' used.
```

so the token S that you have used as `S[table-format=2.0, detect-weight]` is not known.

Adding

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

defines `S` and your document runs without error.

Comment: Thanks! However, when loading the siunitx package in the above MWE I get over 100 error messages starting with a "missing control sequence". How is it possible that you dont get the same error messages?

Comment: @user7378449 You should get no error, as I say only the first error message is important, what does it say?

Comment: The first error message I get when running the MWE with the siunitx package is:

! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.356 \end{frame}
                 
Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
You can recover graciously from this error, if you're careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.

Comment: @user7378449 you got that error from the code posted? that is weird, it is an error from a frame ending on line 356 but the posted example only has 129 lines.

Comment: You are right - I copy-pasted the error from my presentation's log-file. For the MWE the error type remains identical but the line of error is now 127 (after adding siunitx).

! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.127 \end{frame}
                 
Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.

Comment: @user7378449 hard to see how that can be the first error (although that does not mean it is not:-) you could add `\usepackage{siunitx}` and `\listfiles` to the preamble and then show the full log in a code section in your question

Comment: Thanks - I have added the file list above, there is one reported error with inwarerr.sty.

Comment: @user7378449 sorry without showing the error you got with inwarree or siunitx there is not much more I can say, updating your tex system should fix it as there is no error with an up to date texlive 2017

Comment: Updating did the trick - thanks again!